# Exploring Virtual Memory (ProcessWalker)

Tags: c, memory-management, winapi, virtual-memory, heap-memory

I was reading this article on MSDN
["Managing Heap Memory in Win32"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810603.aspx)

And in it they are explaining about a tool called ProcessWalker.exe

In the article they explained that they can use this tool to explore the contents of virtual memory of any process.

1. Does anyone know where I can download this tool from. Or maybe ProcessWalker might be deprecated. Does anyone know any other such tool?
2. And I don't understand how is it even possible for such a tool to exist, wouldn't such a tool cause security breach?

Comment: Yes, that tool and many other such debugging tools available on most popular operating systems are, in fact, security breaches.

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN docs for ReadProcessMemory / VirtualQueryEx

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I looked at VirtualQueryEx(). Yet have to try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

17 years is a *really* long time ago.  Forget everything it says about GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc.  The SysInternals' [VMMap utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) does a similar job, it is excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the vmmap tip. I downloaded the entire sysinternals suite and found it very useful.

Comment: Although, I can't see the actual memory contents using vmmap, but thats okay... my intention was to learn virtual memory management, and its helping a lot.

Comment: Yes, staring at 2 gigabytes of hex dumps doesn't get you anywhere.  You can get that from the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

njoy....

http://hotfile.com/dl/50825402/10ac867/ProcessWalker.rar.html

Comment: Well, I can't download stuff from some file share website.
It has to be from a authenticated source.

But anyway, my purpose is fulfilled by the sysinternals suite (as advised in Han's comment).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @dgw: When using the review tool, it might be useful to actually read the questions you are reviewing answers for. It specifically asks for a link to download ProcessWalker! You cannot "include the essentials parts" of a binary in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The OS must keep information about virtual memory mappings of user processes. Tools such as runtime linkers and loaders explicitly manipulate virtual memory layout of a given process. All these are vital but normal services of the operating system as a whole.

Then there's the monitoring side - how much memory each process is using, what libraries are used by each, what's a page fault rate, etc. etc. All this must be available to userland tools.

The security side of things is managed with user and group permissions, or *capabilities*. Regular user must not be able to inspect memory of other user's process, but should be able to inspect his own. An administrator should then be able to access all the information provides by the system.